# When timer reaches 0 perform some actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if the timer/counter reaches 0?

I want to fade a video out after the timer/counter reaches 0.
Currently it fades the video out right after the video has stopped playing.
I also want to fade or hide the overlay which displays the timers/counters info after it reaches 0.

I was thinking I can't access the timer variable because I would be trying to access a variable outside the scope of the function, but I'm probably wrong. (or am I?)

This is my code:

```
  var video= document.getElementById('vid');
  var overlay= document.getElementById('overlay');
  var timer;
  // Counter;
  function countdown(seconds, callback){
    timer = setInterval(function(){
      document.getElementById("coutdownText").innerHTML = "Recording will start automatically in: " + seconds;
      seconds-- || (clearInterval(timer), callback());
    }, 1000);

    // // TODO: Check if timer reaches 0 here?
  }

  overlay.style.visibility = "hidden";
  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if(video.ended){

      overlay.style.visibility ='visible';
      countdown(10, function(){  alert("Coutdown done!")  });

      $("#vid").show();
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#vid").fadeOut(2500);}, 1000)
      }
  })
```

Comment: You already make that check. But do realise that the execution arrives *immediately* (and only once per new countdown) where you have put TODO, so that is not the right moment to make the check, as there it will always be false. But where you do `seconds--`, that is where it is the *right* moment to check, and so you do.

Comment: Thank you, that makes alot of sense! Oh wow.